# House elves - who taught them to do house chores?

Tags: harry-potter, house-elves

Did House elves have families? 
Who taught them how to cook or clean houses?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, from Harry Potter and the Order of Phoenix

> “Who’s Kreacher?” he asked. 
>   “The house-elf who lives here,” said Ron. “Nutter. Never met one 
>   like him.” 
>   Hermione frowned at Ron. 
>   “He’s not a 
>   nutter,
>    Ron —” 
>   “His life’s ambition is to have hi
>   s head cut off and stuck up on a 
>   plaque **just like his mother**,” said
>    Ron irritably. 
>   “Is that normal, 
>   Hermione?”

So, I assume they have families. <del>Other than this citation I haven't been able to find any other reference about house-elves families, yet.</del>

> “Oh you is a bad elf, Dobby!” 
>   moaned Winky, tears leaking 
>   down her face once more. “My poor Mr. Crouch, what is he doing 
>   without Winky? He is needing me, he
>    is needing my help! I is look-
>   ing after the Crouches all my life, 
>   and **my mother is doing it before 
>   me, and my grandmother is doing it 
>   before her** . . . oh what is they 
>   saying if they knew Winky was 
>   freed? Oh the shame, the shame!” 
>   She buried her fa
>   ce in her skirt again and bawled.
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Ch. *The House-elf Liberation Front*</sub>

So, I think we can make objective conclusion, that house-elves, indeed, have parents, families. But it's hard to tell, what *family* means in this context. Other than Hogwarts I can't remember any place, where there would be more house-elves at one place, living together and working together. Hokey, Dobby, Kreacher, Winky, all seem to be the only *living* house-elf, at the time we meet them. *Winky's* quote **suggests**, that she worked at Crouches together with her mother, even grandmother. If *that is true*, than we can conclude she also learned from them.

As for *what was it like to be an elf-child* I'll quote Winky again:

> “Begging your pardon, miss,” said the house-elf, bowing deeply 
>   again, “but house-elves has **no right to be unhappy when there is 
>   work to be done and masters to be served**.”
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Ch. *The House-elf Liberation Front*</sub>

Even if Winky didn't think so in her youth, she thinks it now. So that gives us another view on the *education* she was given.

I don't know, how old Dobby is,but he does not seem like a kid to me anymore, but I'll quote him anyway:

> "Dobby is used to death threats, sir. Dobby gets them five times a day at home."
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrests, *Ch. The Rogue Bludger*</sub>

Kreacher and Dobby both seem to work for their families not as *first* generation and *probably* could've learnt from their predecessors. Let's support it at least for Kreacher, with a quote from OoP

> passing a row of shrunken heads mounted on plaques on the wall. A closer look showed Harry that the heads belonged to house-elves. **All of them 
>   had the same rather snoutlike nose**.
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Order of Phoenix, Ch. *Number Twelve, Grimmauld Place*</sub>

**Summary**

I do not like speculations and generalizations. I do not know, whether it was always **possible** for house-elf to teach his kid, but I assume it is only natural for a parent to care and teach his child

Comment: Nice sources. Maybe elaborate how the quotes answer the question just for clarity. You know, "based on these quotes we can infer that houses elves ..."

Comment: Did the parent elves taught their kids?  Are there any details available about what was it like to be an Elf-child?